# Move shared 'code_block' from loc-A to loc-B, with only one written instance of 'code_block'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

GOAL: Eliminate redundancy in the initial DOM by implementing reusable JS (or ASP ?).

In this example I want to write some JS to 'bump' the contents of div @ id loc-A to the div @ id loc-B, without having to have the exact same code written in two places on the page.

I'm just not sure where to start...?

I have been able to accomplish this with CSS quite easily, but with redundant code. The more a div element contains, the longer the load.

Here is my codepen example:

See the Pen [redundant_panda](http://codepen.io/rorschaff/pen/reLQYE/) by rorschaff ([@rorschaff](http://codepen.io/rorschaff)) on [CodePen](http://codepen.io).

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media screen and (min-width: 861px) {
  div[id^="loc"] img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #loc-A {
    display: initial;
  }
  #loc-B {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  div[id^="loc"] img {
    width: 50%;
  }
  #loc-A {
    display: none;
  }
  #loc-B {
    position: relative;
    top: 250px;
    display: initial;
  }
}
</style>
</head>


<body>

<div id="loc-A">
<img src="http://bit.ly/1TAzmvg"/>
</div>

<!----- Down the page somewhere ----->

<div id="loc-B">
<img src="http://bit.ly/1TAzmvg" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by bump?

Comment: Move or migrate. In this case, move the image tage to div loc-B. The div's will serve as placeholders for content. The palceholders will populate with content when triggered. Without having the div's in place at the time of loading the page, I lose that location in the DOM. I essentially want to reserve certain locations without having the code populated until needed.

Comment: Is the content actually going to be different, or will it be essentially the same data/interactions but with formatting changes?

Comment: Same content, different place, new css based on the location.

Comment: Based on your comment below, I have no suggestions.

Comment: Thank you @whipdancer . Unfortunately the restrictions make it very difficult, especially when you are used to having full control. I suppose this is the downside of third-party hosting environments. I will proceed to work with what I have then.

Comment: In reference to BUMP. I mean, to Move or migrate. In this case, move the image tage to div loc-B. The div's will serve as placeholders for content. The palceholders will populate with content when triggered. Without having the div's in place at the time of loading the page, I lose that location in the DOM. I essentially want to reserve certain locations without having the code populated until needed.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there's something missing in this, but here's how I would address the code provided.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 861px) {
  div[id^="loc"] img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  div[id^="loc"] img {
    width: 50%;
  }
  #loc-A {
    position: relative;
    top: 250px;
  }
}

#loca-A {
   display: initial;
}
```

And just get rid of the other div.

You could also address this via a responsive framework (bootstrap, foundation) or really, a number of different ways.  I think the better approach would be to think about what problem you are solving and how you are solving it.  If you find yourself using the same code repeatedly, then maybe your how needs to be revisited.

Comment: The major issue is that I can edit, but it is hosted by a third party. I have no direct control over the existing HTML, style sheets, or JavaScript. I have to submit all major changes to them. Essentially, I am working with a reactive template, on the back-end, via the front-end. I can only control what I can see. It is not ideal. So my question involves elements that are not ideal, and yet they are the reality.